# Kendo dropdown inside kendo treeview node

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using Kendo Treeview and inside Kendo Treeview nodes, I have embedded kendo dropdowns.
All works fine, dropdowns appear on Treeview node, but when i expand the treeview node an exception occurs(e is undefined).
Due to this exception When I select any node it doesn't get highlighted like the default kendo treeview behaviour.

When I remove dropdowns, everything works fine.

Please let me know the cause for this exception

Thanks in advance.

```
I have created a fiddle for my issue <http://jsfiddle.net/60wf3nt5/>

when you open the tree nodes and click inside dropdown, exception is thrown
```

Comment: What is "e"? Can you provide some more details?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @JayeshGoyani - find the code sample at http://jsfiddle.net/60wf3nt5/

Comment: Seems to be working in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your fiddle to throw exception however I think that 'e' is actually your 'control' variable in the makeDropDown function or the 'event' variable in the tvDataBound function. Try putting in a null check for this and it should work.